# Removing part of json string with using REGEX

Tags: c#, regex

My json string structure as below

```
...
}],"twitter":[{"id": .... blaa"}]}
...
```

I am trying to remove this part as below

```
Regex.Replace(_VarJson, string.Format("{0}.*?{1}", "\"twitter\":[{", "\"}]"), string.Empty)
```

But nothing removes. Where is my wrong?

Thank you in advance

Comment: `Regex.Replace` **returns** the *modified* string.

Comment: @npinti OK how can I do that? Could you give some sample?

Comment: Don't do Json processing with a regex, any cascading representation should be processed with *context-free grammars*, or use a JSON library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your regex pattern `[{}]` symbols should be escaped with `\` symbol since they are reserved regex symbols (`[]` stands for charactrers group and `{}` stands for repetitions count).

So your replacement could be done as

```
_VarJson = Regex.Replace(_VarJson, 
    string.Format("{0}.*?{1}", 
    "\"twitter\":\\[\\{", "\"\\}\\]"), 
    string.Empty);
```

But I strongly agreed with opinion of @CommuSoft posted in comments - it's better to use some JSON library to parse your source JSON, then remove all you need from object model and write back JSON as text if needed.